# Translation of "What was your name again?"

Tags: traducción, selección-de-palabras, nombres-propios

In English, if someone has already met someone else but later forgets their name, they might ask them something like, "I'm sorry, what was your name again?" (which is less forceful than a blunt "What is your name?"). How would this be expressed in Spanish?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Perdona/Disculpa, ¿cómo te llamabas?
>
> Perdone/Disculpe, ¿cómo se llamaba? (more formal)
>
> Perdona/Disculpa, ¿cúal era tu nombre?
>
> Perdone/Disculpe, ¿cúal era su nombre? (more formal)
>
> Perdona/Disculpa, ¿me puedes decir tu nombre (de nuevo)?
>
> Perdone/Disculpe, ¿me puede decir su nombre de nuevo (de nuevo)? (more formal)

Another ones (thanks Laura)

> Disculpa, no recuerdo tu nombre
>
> Disculpa, ¿Tu nombre era...?

Comment: or "Disculpa, no recuerdo tu nombre" or "Disculpa, ¿Tu nombre era...?"

Comment: @Laurayeah, thanks, there are so many ways..., I've included them

Answer (score 0):

In Colombia, I use (and sometimes I heard) the following phrase:

> ¿Me repite su nombre por favor? (formal)

Also can be added the words *Disculpe/Disculpa* and/or *Perdone/Perdona* at the beginning of the phrase.